# Error Callback if socket does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm using the following code to send message to a specific socket connection.

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', JSON.stringify(data));
```

If a specific "socketid" **does not exist**, Is there a way to catch the error and report it (anything like "socketid does not exist") ?

I'm doing this to avoid **message failures** when Users **refresh** page.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working to check if the socket exists.

```
if(io.sockets.connected[socketid]!=undefined)
console.log("socket exists");
```